# Is nesting eval calls in macros bad practice?

Tags: macros, julia, eval, dsl, compile-time

For illustration, let us say I have the following macros computing rows in a truth table:

```
macro bool_to_lit(a)
    eval(a) ? (x -> x) : (x -> !x)
end

macro make_clause(xs, bools, res)
    lits = map((x -> @eval @bool_to_lit $x), bools.args)
    clause_elements = map.(lits, xs.args)
    and_res = all(push!(clause_elements, res))
    return and_res
end

#@make_clause((false, false), (false, false), true) returns true
```

`@bool_to_lit` returns a closure depending on the value of its argument, and `@make_clause` uses the result to compute values of its own. However, since `@make_clause` uses `@eval`, my understanding is that it actually runs `@bool_to_lit` (and therefore does not just perform a syntactic transformation).

Would it be better (as in faster and generating cleaner code) to avoid use of nested `@eval` in cases such as this, such that the entire result of the whole macro tree is evaluated only once at rutime?

Is it a tradeoff between easier coding (*i.e.* treating nested macros as functions when `@eval` is used) *vs.* correctness (*i.e.* only compile-time syntactic transformations when avoiding nested `@eval`)?

Comment: [you should not use eval inside macro like this.](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/using-eval-inside-macro/8183/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I shortened the logic of your code a bit.  Maybe there's an error I made doing that, but the general point is the same.)*

In most cases, no, you shouldn't use `eval` in a macro.  There are two possible alternatives to what you gave.  First, if you require the macro only to work on literal booleans (ie., the values `true` and `false`), then these are stored right in the AST, and you can do normal computations directly at compile time:

```
julia> macro make_clause_literal(xs, bools, res)
           clause_elements = map((lit, arg) -> lit == arg, bools.args, xs.args)
           res && all(clause_elements)
       end
@make_clause_literal (macro with 1 method)

julia> @macroexpand @make_clause_literal((false, false), (false, false), true)
true
```

There should be some checking added if the inputs really are literal booleans.

On the other hand, if you want to put in other expressions at well, transform the code to something efficient that does the same thing, and leave evaluation to runtime:

```
julia> macro make_clause(xs, bools, res)
           clause_elements = map((lit, arg) -> :($lit == $arg), bools.args, xs.args)
           esc(:($res && $(foldr((e,f) -> :($e && $f), clause_elements))))
       end
@make_clause (macro with 1 method)

julia> @macroexpand @make_clause((false, false), (false, false), true)
:(true && (false == false && false == false))

julia> @macroexpand @make_clause((false, false), (false, x), y)
:(y && (false == false && x == false))
```

Constructing a sequence of `&&` should be as good as it gets in terms of avoiding intermediate arrays and short circuiting.

A third option, which I would recommend, is to write a normal runtime function doing the clause evaluation, and rewriting either of the above macros in terms of a call to that.  I leave that as an exercise.  You could also do a combination of both approaches and evaluate the expression at compile time as far as possible, but I guess the compiler will already do that to some extent.

Comment: Thanks! The example is just for illustration, and I am not looking for runtime optimization, but rather compile-time only computation. I am actually experimenting with the idea depicted in [Type systems as macros](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/stchang/popl2017/)

Comment: Are you trying to do the type checking via SAT solving at compile time, or is the example really just made up?

Comment: I actually am a real amateur in the field (not even science grad), and for the moment being I am just trying to get up to speed with the Julia macro system. My code is drawn from the first example in one of the paper drafts (untyped minimal boolean language DSL). For a really awesome example of an implementation of the idea, see [lexi-lambda's Hackett](https://github.com/lexi-lambda/hackett)

Comment: That syntax example there is pretty mind blowing... and aiming to implement bidirectional type checking as a macro language is a pretty impressive goal for an anesthesiologist -- kudos! Coming back to Julia, you might want to read [this](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0/devdocs/ast/#Surface-syntax-AST-1). And if you are familiar enough with everything to introduce abstractions again, have a look at [`MacroTools`](https://github.com/MikeInnes/MacroTools.jl).

Comment: Thanks! Those are really useful links. Yeah, probably I will not get very far with that, since I suspect this will prove absurdly difficult, but I am quite passionate with computer science and I feel this would be a real benefit to a scientific computing language such as julia